# javascript setCustomValidity didnot work in my context

Tags: javascript, html, customvalidator

I have following code snippet for custom validation:

```
var discountPirces = document.querySelectorAll('.sale-discounted-price input');
for(i=0;i<discountPirces.length;i++)
{
    element = discountPirces[i];
    // if discounted price is more than original price
    if(parseInt(element.value) > parseInt(element.getAttribute('max')))
    {
        element.setCustomValidity('Discounted Price is more than original price');
    }
    // id discounted price falls below 0
    else if(parseInt(element.value) <0)
    {
       element.setCustomValidity('Discounted Price couldnot be less than zero');
    }
    else
    {
       element.setCustomValidity('');
    }
 }
```

This form is for sale of products and allows sales person to set their prices. I need HTML5 validation error and prevent user to submit the form. If i place `alert();` instead of `element.setCustomValidity()` popup comes out.  I don't want to have alert box to show error..

JSFiddle link is- [link for form](https://jsfiddle.net/evve64z3/)

Comment: what is result on `console.log(discountPirces)`.Are you getting elements properly in array.

Comment: Can you share the working code in fiddle or say any errors u get in console which might help to get the error

Comment: Yes, I did... alert and console.log both works under condition

Comment: no error @VinodLouis ... if I put alert instead of setCustomValidity it works... but it looks bad having alert

Comment: `Unfortunately it's not working` - this is not helpful if you want help. In what way is it failing? Do you see any messages in the developer tools console? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi share a fiddle because even parseInt(element.value) can make a diff because parseInt(element.value,10) convert into decimal or error can be in values this way it too vauge to help you

Comment: @JaromandaX- i just changed my question

Comment: @VinodLouis have a look in JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/evve64z3/

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi setCustomValidity is never going to restrict your form submit as its browser specific. i guess you just want a way to let user know he has wrong data try to make use of valid and invalid classes may be it can help https://jsfiddle.net/7fmfgxfr/

Comment: @VinodLouis - thanks man, actually I already saw that question, My issue is- not invoking the HTML5 validator with text like, I used a flag for not submitting the form later